# sar command not found after sierra update

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

I used to use `sar -n DEV 1` to find out about network in El Capitan.

After the update, the same command gives error: `-bash: sar: command not found`.

So, did apple replaced the command with any other one or just removed it?

Is it possible to install `sar` from Apple or 3rd party?

Or is there any other command to find network related data?

Comment: `nettop` probably the closest

Comment: There is `sysstat` implementation of sar, but it was not available on macOS: https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/74. There was sar in OS X 10.4: http://www.andreaswacker.com/blog/2005/11/19/sar-under-os-x-1043/ http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/monitoring-cpu-load-memory-usage-mac-os-command-line-terminal/ and there is sar in FreeBSD as [sysutils/bsdsar](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-bsdsar-installation-configuration/) http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/bsdsar http://web.archive.org/web/20100610021800/http://googlebit.com/bsdsar/

Answer (score 6):

Apple's source code repository for `sar` is [located here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-643.30.1/sar.tproj/). Download **sar.c** and **sar.h**.

You will also need **sadc.h** and **sadc.c** [from here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-643.30.1/sadc.tproj/).

Compile and test:

```
clang sar.c -o sar -I .
clang sadc.c -o sadc -I . -framework Foundation -framework IOKit

./sar -A -f test > testout
terminated by signal SIGFPE (Floating point exception)
```

Then the content of the **testout** file looks like this:

```
17:32:23  %usr  %nice   %sys   %idle

17:32:23    pgout/s

17:32:23     pgin/s        pflt/s        vflt/s

17:32:23   device    r+w/s    blks/s

17:32:23    IFACE    Ipkts/s      Ibytes/s     Opkts/s      Obytes/s

17:32:23    IFACE     Ierrs/s     Oerrs/s    Coll/s      Drop/s
New Disk: [disk0] IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/SATA@1F,2/PRT0@0/PMP@0/@0:0

17:32:23  %usr  %nice   %sys   %idle
17:32:23    0      0      0      0

17:32:23    pgout/s
17:32:23        nan

17:32:23     pgin/s        pflt/s        vflt/s
17:32:23        nan           nan           inf
```

So it compiles, data can be collected and kindof processed, but not fully.

I've found the Apple repository of SAR thanks to this superuser answer: https://superuser.com/a/581128

Comment: is `--enable-install-cron` somehow special?

Comment: The cron feature enable sysstat to collect data and other analytics task happening routinely and in background. I think you can avoid using that flag if you plan to use only the sar utility! Remember to point to correct headers file!

Comment: i've added addition details

Comment: I guess it makes sense to remove references to `sysstat` package.

Comment: i removed the sysstat package references as you suggest